# Java приведение массива примитивов к Object[]. Возможно ли?

Tags: массивы, java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Задался целью передать в метод любой массив.

Проблема возникла с передачей массива примитивов, так как примитивы не производны от Object, соответственно и их массивы так же.

Собственно, вопрос - как передать в метод массив любых примитивов?

UPD:
Вариант с передачей множественных аргументов (`public void someMethod(Object... args)`) не устраивает, так как у меня тип аргумента обрабатывается через карту `Map<Class<?>, ISerializer>`, потому и выборка нужна именно по критерию "массив примитивов".

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, пример массива приведите в виде кода, а то не совсем ясно, как и что вы собираетесь делать. Везде, вроде, есть обертки, автобоксинги и проч., но вы говорите все это не то. Так что нужна конкретика.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение: перегрузите (overload) Ваш метод для всех возможных примитивов следующим образом:

```
public void someMethod(Object[] args) {
    //your code
}

public void someMethod(int[] ints) {
    Object[] args = new Object[ints.length];
    for (int i=0; i<ints.length; i++) {
        args[i] = (Object) ints[i];
    }
    return someMethod(args);
}
```

Теперь Вы можете вызывать ваш метод, передавая ему массив int, а реализацию метода писать для массива Object.

Comment: Да, не догадался... Самое оно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Передавайте массив обёрток над примитивами (`Integer`, `Double` и т. д.), они именно для этих целей и были созданы.

Comment: Как я уже писал, мне нужна именно возможность передать неконкретный массив примитивов... Про обертки я прекрасно знаю, но это в конкретно моём случае неудобно.

Comment: А ничего другого вам не остаётся. Дженерики не работают с примитивами ни в кком виде, только со ссылочными типами.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то есть абстрактный класс Number. От которого наследованы всякие Long,Double, Integer. И как жалко что нету класса какого нибудь "PrimitiveWrapper" :)

Comment: Как я уже писал, мне нужна именно возможность передать неконкретный массив примитивов... Про обертки я прекрасно знаю, но это в конкретно моём случае неудобно.

К тому же, обертки я могу отправить как Object[], они прекрасно работают.

Comment: ...и от которого НЕ унаследованы `Character` и `Boolean`, также являющиеся обёрками над примитивами.

Comment: `  Boolean bool = new Boolean(true);
  System.out.println("Boolean is instance of Object? " + (bool instanceof Object));
  Character cha = new Character('x');
  System.out.println("Character is instance of Object? " + (cha instanceof Object));`


Boolean is instance of Object? true
Character is instance of Object? true


Что я делаю не так?

Comment:     Boolean bool = new Boolean(true);
    System.out.println("Boolean is instance of Number? " + (bool instanceof Number));
    Character cha = new Character('x');
    System.out.println("Character is instance of Number? " + (cha instanceof Number));

Boolean is instance of Number? false
Character is instance of Number? false

Прежде чем писать что-то потрудитесь внимательно прочесть то, что написали до вас. Комментарий относился к ответу @argamidon, предлагавшего использовать `Number`, но не учитывающего существование таких примитивов как `Boolean` и `Character`.